# ElementClickInterceptedException QA automation

Tags: python, spring, testing, automation, sita

ElementClickInterceptedException, suggests that the button you're trying to click with the CSS selector "button.btn.btn--primary.nextStep[data-step-target='#step3']" is not clickable because something is intercepting the click action at that specific point.

trying to click on next page and it is not clickable

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Some other element is overlaying that button, so that trying to click on the button would click on the other element instead.  What is your actual question?